# Does the device go to sleep while in call?

Tags: android, call

Can an android device go to sleep during the duration of phone call ?

I have read that device does go to sleep when the device is idle and there are no wake locks. But I am not sure if having a running call accounts for the wakelock.

Comment: No, only screen is off to avoid the touches during the call. Proximartri sensor is used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During a phone call the phone is not asleep, it just turns off the screen so you won't accidentally touch the <kbd>End call</kbd> button.